# how to get child Items from gallery android?

Tags: android, image-gallery

I want to get the image from gallery.For this I used

```
  View v= mGallery.childAt(index);
   ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
```

But sometimes if that indexed images is not visible that time it is giving

> NullPointerException.

How to get the non-visible image from gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are adding the images to the gallery via an adapter?
If so you can use [`getItemAtPosition(index)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29) to basically retrieve what you have put into the adapter. Of course you need to make sure that index is valid.

If you want the selected item, you have other options that gives you direct access: 
[`Gallery.getSelectedView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#getSelectedView%28%29) and [`Gallery.getSelectedItem()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem%28%29)

Comment: Iam trying to get the item but when the gallery is moving positions are changing?How to know the previous pressed image position.I already taken on variable for pressed position.But that position may be not persist.

Comment: mGallery.getItemAtPostion(position); giving object.If I cast this object to View v =(View)Object;It is giving castexception.Please give me snippet on this.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more options. If you want to access the selected item, there are other methods possible.

Comment: I want to access the non visible item view.For that I tried childAt method but when the item is not visible it is giving nullpointer exception.

Comment: How do you put the images into the gallery in the first step? It would for sure help if you'd post that code.

Answer (score -1):

Oh that was one way and better way buddy to get images and show them (I described in my above answer).

To resolve your problem I can only show you some tricks or patches to apply in your code.

For that you can check for null condition. If you are getting null image then show some default image in place of it.

Comment: This looks like a comment rather an answer, possibly it was in response to Heiko Rupp. However, it barely contains any answer material in its own right, so I suggest it is deleted. Could you do that, N-JOY?